# WebDriverException: failed to wait for extension background page to load: xxx Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I try to add an extension on my script like for example "Selenium" I get this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException:
  Message: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background.html
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
```

Code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

executable_path = "chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('MetaMask.crx')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading MetaMask version to 9.01 solved this, something must have changed in the most recent 10.x versions.